# Edit item popups not working with ms-listviewtable class in a CEWP

Tags: jquery, content-editor-web-part, popup

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and Internet Explorer 9. (I have no choice in browser or versions -- policy dictates I use these until told otherwise)

I actually solved my problem, but I still don't understand why there was a problem, and I really want to understand why. The solution makes no sense to me. To paraphrase Douglas Adams, I speculate that if I knew exactly why this happened, I would know a lot more about the nature of the (SharePoint) Universe than I do now.

### The problem I was having:

I have a page with many web parts. In a couple of content-editor webparts, I have javascript/jquery using the load() function to load in some list views, like this:

```
$("#ListofSubscribersPlaceHolder").load(SubscriberView+" .ms-listviewtable",function(responseTxt,status,xhr) {
     if ( status == "error" ) alert( "Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );

     if (responseTxt.contains("no items to show")) {
       $("#ListofSubscribersPlaceHolder").html("<p>No subscribers yet.</p>");
    }

    else {
       // Remove the header row
       $("#ListofSubscribersPlaceHolder table").find("tr").first().remove();
    }
});
```

The list view includes the Edit icon and associated A-tag for each list item, with an onclick calling EditItemWithCheckoutAlert, which pops up the edit item form, and an href loading the edit item as a page instead of a pop-up.

When you visit the list view as a separate page, the Edit item works as you would expect, with a pop-up. But when you click on it in the web part, it follows the href to a web page instead of doing the pop-up form.

Other pop-ups that used the NewItem2 function in their onclick= worked fine. I set up alerts to show the A-tag after the page was fully rendered, and the onclick was definitely defined.

### The solution I found:

Through digging and trial and error, I finally discovered that the problem went away (i.e. the popups work) if I removed the ms-listviewtable class from the table containing the link. So I added this line after the line that removes the header row:

```
$("#ListofSubscribersPlaceHolder table").removeClass("ms-listviewtable");
```

and now it works perfectly.

### My Question:

I'm completely baffled as to why a class would prevent the onclick from working but let the href work. Looking at the stylesheets being pulled in, ms-listviewtable just defines borders and colors -- nothing fancy as far as I can tell.

In my search for a solution, I searched for how one might deliberately do such a thing. Aside from remonstrances that using css to modify behavior is wrong, there were 2 basic answers:

1. The pointer-events attribute. I checked that (with an alert of the A-tag's $(this).css("pointer-events")), and it is undefined. (Any other attributes I should check?)
2. Other suggestions involved covering the edit icon with an invisible unclickable layer, but wouldn't that also disable the href link? At any rate, I found no evidence that this was being done.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

### Try it yourself

If you want to see for yourself, try adding this code:

```
<table class=ms-listviewtable>
<tbody><tr><td>TEST:</td>
<td>
<a onclick="EditItemWithCheckoutAlert(event,'http://www.google.com','0','','','/','','955');return false;" href="http://www.google.com"><IMG border=0 alt=Edit src="/_layouts/images/edititem.gif"></a>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

With `class=ms-listviewtable`, I get a fresh page with google in it; without it, I get a pop-up on the current page (with an error saying it can't put that page in an iframe, but that's irrelevant: the point is that you get a popup, i.e. the onclick works).

If you can't reproduce it on SharePoint 2010, let me know, because then I can look for local anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to load an edit form.

My suggestion would be to use a dialog box instead of a pop up. Pop-up is probably going to get blocked by a lot of browsers, especially your network has strict policies.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-open-a-list-form-in-a-modal-dialog-box.aspx

```
    <input onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '../Lists/GBE/NewForm.aspx', title: 'User Survey' }); return false;" id="btnVote" type="button" value="Vote" />
```

I normally use something like this. Sorry I can't directly answer as to why your method behaved the way it did.

Comment: Sorry if I used the wrong term. It is a dialog box I am trying to use, not a pop up. The problem is that edit form dialog box only works if the icon for it does not have the class ms-listviewtable applied to it, and I'm wondering how in the world the class can cause that to happen.